# Sql Exception related to DataSet in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, exception, dataset

I want to get values of a id specified row in my "Service Fees" table. When I try to execute following code an exception, which says "An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code.Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '**a34**'."

Is it about Dataset object?

PS: The id is; ee83089d-4**a34**-46e0-be6c-b8b506f31a8e

```
 if (Request.QueryString["MyId"] != null)
            {
                isUpdate = true;
                var id = Request.QueryString["MyId"].ToString();

                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ServiceFees WHERE Id=" + id, connection);
                SqlDataAdapter adapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapter2.Fill(ds);

                sf1.name = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();

            }
```

Comment: that allows sql injection, ought to be parameterized.

Comment: need to include the quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose your id in single quote, it should look like :

```
 SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ServiceFees WHERE Id='" + id +"'", connection);
```

Id is GUID and it should be enclosed within single quotes.

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger Yes, you are right one should always use parametrized query.

Comment: I will be careful about sql injections. Now I'm just trying. Anyway thank you all for replies

Comment: @black_books just a line of code more and you have everything under control

Answer (score 1):

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ServiceFees WHERE Id= @id", connection);
cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("id",id));
```

to avoid sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

Beware of **SQL Injection**

**Dont pass parameters in single quotes,Double quotes**

Always use `SqlParameter` Class

As your Parameter is String You need to Pass it As `string` DataType

```
string Id="ee83089d-4a34-46e0-be6c-b8b506f31a8e";
    SqlParameter para1=new SqlParameter("@Id",SqlDbType.Varchar,500);
    para1.Value=Id;
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ServiceFees WHERE Id=@Id" , connection);
cmd2.Parameters.Add(para1);

SqlDataAdapter adapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the id unquoted to SQL.

As a result it's probably trying to calculate the result of ee83089d-4a34-46e0-be6c-b8b506f31a8e.

You probably want:

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ServiceFees WHERE Id='" + 
  id + "'", connection);
```

Or some other SQL call which isn't vulnerable to injection attacks.